# LINQ to Entities .contains is ignoring results with NULL

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am new to the Entity Framework, and am struggling with what I hope is a basic problem. My code is here:

```
    Dim accounts As List(Of STUDENT) =
        (From a In SA.STUDENTs
         Where (a.MATRIC_NO.Contains(matric) And a.FIRST_NAME.Contains(firstName) And a.MIDDLE_NAMES.Contains(middleName) And a.SURNAME.Contains(lastName) And a.PREFERRED_NAME.Contains(preferredName))
         Select a).ToList
```

The query runs fine, until one of the search fields is NULL in the database. If, for instance, a matric number is entered in the seach interface but middle name is left blank, the query will not return any records if middle name is NULL in the database. If middle name is a blank space in the database then it will return the record.

Can anyone offer any pointers?

Many thanks!

Comment: but NULL doesn't contain anything, right?

Comment: If the value entered into the query is not blank, then the query should return a matching record. If the value entered in blank, then it should return any record, even in the value is NULL. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra check in your query. For example:

```
public function filterList(IEnumerable list, string name)
{
    var filtered_list = list.Where(x=> x.Name.Contains(name) || string.IsNullorWhitespace(name)).ToList();

    return filtered_list;
}
```

So you can see, if the `name` variable is empty, all elements will return true, so all elements will be return (no real filter applied).

So basically, you can change all filters from

```
something.Contains(anotherthing)
```

to

```
something.Contains(anotherthing) || string.IsnullOrWhitespace(anotherthing)
```

Comment: I always forget the correct capitalization on IsNullorWhitespace, sorry about that.

Comment: Is `IsNullOrWhitespace` implemented in SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Struggling to get this to work though, the runtime error is that LINQ to Entities does not recognise IsNullOrWhitespace.

Comment: I'm not sure this would accomplish what I need to it do though. What I need to happen is that if a user enters a value into one of the conditions, then the query should return all matching records, even if one of the other fields being searched on is NULL.

Comment: If you have a filter active (let's say you're looking for 'smith' in the column LastName), rows with `NULL` in the LastName column shouldn't be shown since they do not contain the searched string. However, if your filter on LastName is `null`/`string.Empty`, all rows should be shown, including the ones that have `NULL` in the lastname column. But you can't call the `.Contains()` function on a `NULL` (which by definition isn't a string).

Answer (score 0):

```
(From a In SA.STUDENTs
         Where isnull(a.MATRIC_NO.Contains(matric) And a.FIRST_NAME.Contains(firstName) And a.MIDDLE_NAMES.Contains(middleName) And a.SURNAME.Contains(lastName) And a.PREFERRED_NAME.Contains(preferredName))
         Select a).ToList
```

Like this `:select * from tbl where statusid = isnull(@statusid,statusid)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm writing in VB rather than C# though! I'll try and translate this to VB and check it out.

Comment: Dim accounts As List(Of STUDENT) =
        (From a In SA.STUDENTs
         Where (**a.matric == null || a.MATRIC_NO.Contains(matric)** And a.FIRST_NAME == null || a.FIRST_NAME.Contains(firstName) And a.MIDDLE_NAMES.Contains(middleName) And a.SURNAME.Contains(lastName) And a.PREFERRED_NAME.Contains(preferredName))
         Select a).ToList

Comment: That's still C# though. I know it's a query, but it gets kicked out when I try to enter it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

try like this ..

```
   Dim get_rmf_2 = From rmf In t_rmf _
          Where Not IsDBNull(rmf!NIVP) AndAlso rmf!NIVP = nivp_rap
```

this is in VB I think this is works fine

Comment: Hmm, code is valid but Entity Framework does not recognise the IsDBNull. It causes a runtime error. I'll keep plugging away!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using a different approach. If there was no value entered for a particular field, leave it out the query. I accomplished this using predicates, as below:

```
    'create the base query
    Dim accounts =
        (From a In SA.STUDENTs
         Select a)


    'create predicates for each condition required in the query
    If matric <> "" Then
        accounts = accounts.Where(Function(m) m.MATRIC_NO.Contains(matric))
    End If

    If firstName <> "" Then
        accounts = accounts.Where(Function(f) f.FIRST_NAME.Contains(firstName))
    End If

    If middleName <> "" Then
        accounts = accounts.Where(Function(mn) mn.MIDDLE_NAMES.Contains(middleName))
    End If

    If lastName <> "" Then
        accounts = accounts.Where(Function(l) l.SURNAME.Contains(lastName))
    End If

    If preferredName <> "" Then
        accounts = accounts.Where(Function(p) p.PREFERRED_NAME.Contains(preferredName))
    End If

    'execute the query
    Dim accountlist = accounts.ToList

    'return the results
    Return accountlist
```

If anyone can see anything wrong with this, or any gotchas that I'm unaware of, please let me know! I'm very new to LINQ to Entities, and LINQ in general!